# HTTP PUT not working

Tags: c#, http, powershell

I'm trying to use this function to send a string.

```
function submit_report_http
{
    param($report)
    trap{return 1}
    if($verbose -gt 1){minfo 'Sending report via http, url is ' + $http_url}
    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($http_url)
    $webRequest.ContentType = "text/html"
    $PostStr = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($report)
    $webrequest.ContentLength = $PostStr.Length
    $webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = $false
    if($verbose -gt 1){minfo ' authenticating user: ' + $http_user}
    $webRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $http_user, $http_pass
    $webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true
    $webRequest.Method = "PUT"
    $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
    $requestStream.Write($PostStr, 0,$PostStr.length)
    $requestStream.Flush()
    $requestStream.Close()
}
```

When I get to the line:

```
$requestStream = $webrequest.GetRequestStream()
```

The script seems to go in to an infinite loop.

Can anyone see the problem?

Gísli

Comment: are you sure HTTP PUT enabled on your server?

Comment: Yes, it's being used by other scripts

Comment: You could try using Fiddler on the client to see if there's something happening with the request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using WireShark to see what's happening on the wire and also checking your server logs.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find anything wrong. It must have been some sort of network problem. But it's working now